# How can I investigate the cause of a single deployment spawning two replicasets?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes deployment that for some reason creates two replicasets. I can't figure out why. When I do `kubectl describe rs <NAME>`, they both say they're managed by the same deployment. It does it consistently when I delete and recreate the deployment. Does anyone have any pointers for investigating what could be causing this?

Comment: Is any pod created by the deployment crashing or restarting? Do you see both the ReplicaSets in the output of `kubectl describe deploy coredns -n=kube-system | grep -i replicaset` and `kubectl get deploy coredns -n=kube-system -o yaml | grep -i replicaset`?

Comment: Do you see the difference between rs? Are they both created when you create deployment? You can see 2 rs during the update as old one stick around for some time, but only last one is actually a real one.

Comment: provide more information of kubectl describe deployment <NAME>, kubectl describe rs <NAME> and kubectl describe pod <NAME> , so that we can check how to investigate on it.

Comment: share the output from below command

Comment: kubectl describe po >pod-name>

Comment: sharing the deployment yaml could also be useful.

Comment: Thanks everybody, @VikramHosakote had the right idea that it was apparently just because the replicas were coming up unhealthy.

Comment: I am ok with closing this question if people think it's a good idea